# Drawing Cylindrical Segment with Graphics3D

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, mathworld

For a visualization I need a combination of 3 Cylindrical segments to visualize the incident, reflected and refracted beam of light at a surface. I got as far as the following code.

```
Graphics3D[{
  Polygon[{{-1.5, -1.5, 0}, {1.5, -1.5, 0}, {1.5, 1.5,0}, {-1.5, 1.5, 0}}], 
  Polygon[{{-1.5, 0, -1.5}, {1.5, 0, -1.5}, {1.5, 0, 1.5}, {-1.5, 0,1.5}}],
  Opacity[0.5], 
  Cylinder[{{-1, 1, 0}, {0.2, -0.2, 0}}, 0.2], 
  Cylinder[{{-0.2, -0.2, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}, 0.2], 
  Scale[Cylinder[{{-0.05, 0.125, 0}, {0.5, -1, 0}}, 0.25], {1, 1,0.8}]
}]
```

results in the following output

[image: Mathematica Screenshot]

Obviously, the remaining "stumps" of the cylinder segments on the respective other side of the reflection plane need to be removed. I do not want to go to too complex approaches like using Parametric surfaces or similar mathematical descriptions of a cylindrical segment, mainly for performance reasons (all of these methods are getting rather slow to plot). There is an interesting method documented in [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CylindricalSegment.html), but the link to the `` ExtraPackages`Hidekazu`Knife` `` package is [broken](http://www3.kawase-h.ed.jp/Teachers/~Takahashi/index.html), and the more recent [link](http://kanotono.dynalias.com/MyProject/index.html) ends in 2007 too (checked through Wayback).

Maybe there are much simpler hacks to remove the unwanted cylinder areas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`ShearingTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ShearingTransform.html):

```
Graphics3D[{Polygon[{{-1.5, -1.5, 0}, {1.5, -1.5, 0}, {1.5, 1.5, 
     0}, {-1.5, 1.5, 0}}], 
  Polygon[{{-1.5, 0, -1.5}, {1.5, 0, -1.5}, {1.5, 0, 1.5}, {-1.5, 0, 
     1.5}}], Opacity[0.5], 
  GeometricTransformation[Cylinder[{{-1, 1, 0}, {0.0, 0, 0}}, 0.2], 
   ShearingTransform[ -Pi/4, {-1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}]],
  GeometricTransformation[Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}, 0.2], 
   ShearingTransform[ -Pi/4, {1, 1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}]],
  Scale[
   GeometricTransformation[
    Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0.5, -1, 0}}, 0.25], 
    ShearingTransform[ -ArcTan[1/2.], {.5, -1, 0}, {-1, -.5, 0}]], {1,
     1, 0.8}]}]
```

[image: sheared]

The shearing angles are calculated by hand from the specific incident and refracted angles you used. It could of course be automated, too.

To shear the caps of the cylinders without deforming the cylinder cross section, the first argument of `ShearingTransform` has to be a vector along the cylinder axis, and the second argument points perpendicular to the ray (in the plane of incidence).

Comment: +1 a really nice idea. Exactly what I looked for

Answer (score 3):

Since your are simulating Light, why not use Tube

```
tube1IncidentAndReflection={{-1,1,0},{0,0,0},{1,1,0}};
tube2IncidentAndRefraction={{-1,1,0},{0,0,0},{.6,-1,0}};
Graphics3D[{Polygon[{{-1.5,-1.5,0},{1.5,-1.5,0},{1.5,1.5,0},{-1.5,1.5,0}}],Polygon[{{-1.5,0,-1.5},{1.5,0,-1.5},{1.5,0,1.5},{-1.5,0,1.5}}],Opacity[0.5],Tube[tube1IncidentAndReflection],Tube[tube2IncidentAndRefraction]}]
```

And you can set the `JoinForm`， amr's remind of `CapForm` .
[image]

[image]
So still some problem described as Jens' comment

Comment: But this doesn't hide the intersecting caps properly at the branch point, which is the main point of the question. You can see this more clearly by increasing the `Tube` radius in your example.

Comment: remember there is also `CapForm`

Comment: @amr,  yes, me silly, hehe